# "release" command from sbt-release plugin is not recognized

Tags: sbt

I can't get the sbt-release plugin to work at all. The "sbt release" command is not recognized.

As per plugin's documentation, I have this entry added to my ./project/plugins.sbt file in my play application:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "0.8.5")
```

And I'm running the latest to-date 0.13.6 version of sbt launcher. Here's the error that I get when I execute "sbt release" from my project directory:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/Projects/project
[info] Loading [pom.xml]
[info] Use auto-generated Build object
[success] POM definition loaded
[info] Set current project to integration (in build file:/Users/Projects/project/)
[error] Not a valid command: release (similar: reload, eclipse, last)
[error] Not a valid project ID: release
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: release (similar: rpmRelease, rpm-release, resolvers)
[error] release
[error]        ^
```

And just to make sure, that sbt-release plugin does get loaded into the project, I execute "sbt about", and it does show that sbt-release is in the list of Available Plugins. But again, for some reason, "sbt release" command is not recognized.

```
> sbt about
...
[info] Available Plugins: ... sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As per sbt-release plugin documentation, added this line into my build.sbt file, and it did it! "sbt release" command is now being recognized.

```
releaseSettings
```

For some reason, it did not work for me the first time I tried it earlier. Something must have been going on in my environment or earlier version of my build.sbt file.